# В браузере не выводится HTML

Tags: html, django

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>Главная - Доска объявлений</titlе>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Объявления</h1>

        <div>
            <h2>Дом</h2>
            <p>трёхэтажный,дерево</р>
            <р>04.09.2019 11:48:12</р>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h2>Дача</h2>
            <p>Два этажа,газ,летний душ,все удобства,гараж</р>
            <р>04.09.2019 11:36:46</р>
        </div>

    </body>  
</html>
```

Почему на странице браузера не отображается этот код? `<title>` выводится, а `<body>` нет.

Comment: Вы попутали раскладку и в тегах написали русские буквы вместо английских.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас нелегальные символы в тэгах. Чтобы Ваш HTML отобразился, напишите правильно тэги `title`, `p`, вот так:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>Главная - Доска объявлений</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Объявления</h1>

        <div>
            <h2>Дом</h2>
            <p>трёхэтажный,дерево</p>
            <p>04.09.2019 11:48:12</p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h2>Дача</h2>
            <p>Два этажа,газ,летний душ,все удобства,гараж</p>
            <p>04.09.2019 11:36:46</p>
        </div>

    </body>  
</html>
```